# Vue.js: how to load a template inside an async component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I'm brand new to [vuejs](/questions/tagged/vuejs) and I'm trying to get a simple site set up with it. I have a component for each page (About us, Contact us, etc).

This is my **working** starting point

```
Vue.component('about-us', {
    template: '<div>...lots of markup...</div>'
});
```

I want to transform that code into something that works asynchronously. Attempting to follow the docs, here is my code:

```
Vue.component('about-us', function(resolve, reject){
    let template_string = '';

    // Load the template with ajax
    $.post(ajax_url, {'action': 'get_about_page'}, function(r){
        r = JSON.parse(r);

        // Save the template string
        if( r.success ) {
            template_string = r.data;
        }
    });

    // Resolve callback for Vue
    resolve({
        template: template_string
    });
});
```

The error I get is:

> [Vue warn]: Failed to mount component: template or render function not
>   defined. found in ---> Anonymous Root

**Question:** Is my approach wrong? Is it a syntax problem? I'm not sure if I'm on the right path. (yes I have jQuery loaded)

Comment: Put the `resolve` call in the callback: `if (r.success) { resolve({ template: r.data }) }`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your resolve into the ajax callback.

```
Vue.component('about-us', function(resolve, reject){
    // Load the template with ajax
    $.post(ajax_url, {'action': 'get_about_page'}, function(r){
        r = JSON.parse(r);

        // Save the template string
        if( r.success ) {
            // Resolve callback for Vue
            resolve({
              template: r.data
            });
        } else {
          reject("Unable to define component!")
        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Im using this construction_

```
Vue.component('about-us', function (resolve, reject) {
  $.post('ajax_url', {'action': 'get_about_page'}, 'html')
   .done(function (data) {
     resolve({template: data})
   })
})
```